# EditText, inside Listview, cursor moves to front when call setLayoutParams();

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, cursor

I have an `EditText` inside of a `RelativeLayout` (named `TopLayout` in code below) that is inside of a `ListView`. There is TextWatcher on the `EditText` that changes the height of the `RelativeLayout` (and `ListView`). But when the height changes, the cursor inside of the `EditText` moves to the beginning.

Is there anyway to get it to stay where it is?

```
public void setItemHeight(int itemPos, int itemHeight) {
    if (mChallengingThoughtsListView != null) {

        View itemView = mChallengingThoughtsListView.getChildAt(itemPos);
        LinearLayout topLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TopLayout);

        // Set item height
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = topLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = itemHeight;
        topLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        // TODO: Put code to place cursor back where it was
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `TopLayout` a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`? You said that it is relativelayout but on your code it is linearlayout.

Comment: Btw that is not the issue. Maybe you can try to get first the current focused edittext before your set the height of the `toplayout`, then after the `topLayout` is changed, call `currentFocusedEditText.requestFocus()`

Comment: @Tepits you are correct, it is a `LinearLayout`. I will correct the post. I have a theory that I will test tonight. I will get the cursor position at the beginning of the function and set a `onLayoutChangeListener`, that sets the cursor position, before I call `setLayoutParams()`. I'll post results